# Sending variables behind the scenes from PHP to whatever absolute or relative page?

Tags: php, post

How do I post them to whatever page from here and how can I send these variables to several pages at the same time?

```
//catched those variables within the same page
$event = $_POST['event'];
$when = $_POST['eventdate'];
$where = $_POST['place'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
send $event, $when, $where, ... to("whateverurl1");//not the way
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSTing data to an URL can be done with the [curl extension](http://www.php.net/curl), which allows one to send HTTP requests from PHP.

In your case, something like this might do the trick :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'event' => $event, 
    'when' => $when, 
    // ... more here
));
$returned = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

For more informations you might want to take a look at the manual page of [`curl_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php), and for more options *(there are a lot of possible options !)*, see [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt).

Here, the most important ones are :

- `CURLOPT_URL` : to specify the URL to which you want to post your data
- `CURLOPT_POST` : as you want to send an HTTP POST request -- and not GET, which is the default
- `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` : to specify the data that you want to send

But note this will not send several queries in parallel -- maybe [`curl_multi_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) and the other `curl_multi_*` functions could help, there...

Comment: Ok but do I have to include something because:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Comment: Oh, so not cool :-( ;; that function not being defined means the curl extension is not installed/enabled on your server ;-(  ;;; maybe, if enabled on your server, a solution would be to use `fopen` + a stream context to send an HTTP POST request (see the example #1 on http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php ) ;; else, you'll have to go to a library that uses `fsockopen`...

Comment: Ok I guess this work if it's enabled, thanks or shouldn't I check you're answer guessing?